# What does the third parameter of plt.plot() in matplotlib do?

Tags: python, matplotlib

`plt.plot()` usually accepts x,y and format. But if I pass third argument as data another line is plotted. I can't understand the relationship.

```
x=np.linspace(0,10,5)
plt.plot(x,x,x,label='linear')
plt.grid()
```

Created plot:
[image: Find the output of above code here]

Comment: .plot can plot multiple lines, i.e (x1,y1,x2,y2). The second line is basically x plotted against index, like (x1,y1,y2) where x1 and y1 plotted normally and y2 plotted against index (here its 0-4)

Comment: See https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html There are many ways to pass parameters to `plt.plot`

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it answered your question - that way the question is marked as such for future users.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) of the docs outlines the call signatures for `matplotlib.pyplot.plt()`. Specifically relevant here is the signature

```py
plot([x], y, [fmt], [x2], y2, [fmt2], ..., **kwargs)
```

And the parameter description

> **x, y**: array-like or scalar
>
> > The horizontal and vertical components of the data points. `x` values are optional and default to `range(len(y))`.

When you do something like

```py
plt.plot(x,x,x)
```

You are actually specifying a first set of `x` values followed by the corresponding `y` values and then a second set of `y` values which are paired with the default `x` values of `range(len(y))` and plotted, resulting in two lines.